# Add texture images on each face of a 3d cube using Direct3d windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, textures, direct3d

I have managed to draw a 3D cube using Direct3D for windows phone 8.

I would like to draw different image texture on each face of the cube and change the image texture position to a different face of the cube on rotation of the cube.

Any lead with sample code will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide some code of your working 3D cube, then we may help more easily to add a texture

Comment: I have found this example from nokia http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_a_DirectX_texture_with_a_picture    it somehow does what I wanted but would like to have different images for each face of the cube, the code that I have is the one used from that example you can use that to help

Comment: Please help us help you. We shouldn't have to download example code from the nokia site. You should post the relevant snippets here.